# How to prove: When the product of two complex numbers is a real number, the complex numbers are proportional to each other's conjugates.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Looking for a solution to the problem: Given
$ z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbf(z_1)\cdot(z_2) \in \mathbb{R}$,
prove $ z_1 = p\cdot\overline z_2$ for any $ p\in\mathbb{R} $.

Comment: There are several equivalent ways to define multiplication of complex numbers. Are you look for an answer in terms of the numbers expressed as polar co-ordinates for example?

Comment: If you provide some background, where you found the problem, what you've tried, etc, people may vote to take the question off hold.

Comment: "for any $p$" ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to use is the equivalence $z \in \mathbb{R} \Longleftrightarrow  z = \overline{z}$.

Assume $z_1 . z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $z_1z_2 = \overline{z_1z_2}$. Assume moreover ${z_2 \neq 0}$. Then $\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}} = \frac{\overline{z_1}}{z_2} = \overline{(\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}})}$, i.e. $\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}}$ equals its conjugate. It follows that $\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}} = p \in \mathbb{R}$. If $z_2 = 0$, then $z_1 = p.\overline{z_2}$ if and only if $z_1=0$. If $z_1 \neq 0$, there is no solution for $p$.

Comment: Typo top line? $z=\overline{z}$?

Comment: This is what I wrote on top line (using latex "\bar" instead "\overline"). Does it appear differently on your screen?

Comment: Yes, you're right, you did latex in "\bar" it's difficult to see on my screen - anyway your response to the OP is valid and perfectly reasonable and I see the question has been put on hold. All the best!

Comment: Changed to "\overline" which is nicer indeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$, if $wz=r\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
w|z|^2=wz\bar{z}=r\bar{z}\implies w=\frac{r}{|z|^2}\bar{z}
$$
So $p=\dfrac{r}{|z|^2}$.